# Sync with Gradle for project 'HelloWorld' failed: Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createNativeBuildModel

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I have just upgraded Android Studio to version 2.0 and am getting the following error message

> Sync with Gradle for project 'HelloWorld' failed: Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createNativeBuildModel

The build file looks like

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

model {

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 15
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.test.helloworld"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
        }
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
            jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDirs "libs"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled = false
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/xxx.jar')
        compile files('libs/xxx1.jar')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This gradle build error does not appear after updating to the latest Android Studio version 2.1.1